# Serialize and Deserialize Trie-like Data Structure

Tags: java, recursion, serialization, deserialization, trie

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a Trie-like data structure which has data/character in each node. So to form a whole word, traversal from root to leaf node is required.

Serialization and De-serialization should be in pre-order traversal i.e. process the children in DFS approach.

`#` marks end of traversal for that node i.e. that the trie-like node doesn't have any more children.

Here is what I have tried.

```
public class SerializeDeserialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prepare TrieNode Tree
        TrieNodeSD root = buildTrienodeTree();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        serialize(root, sb);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println();
        TrieNodeSD newRoot = deserialize(sb.toString().split(","), new int[] {0});
        StringBuilder newsb = new StringBuilder();
        serialize(newRoot, newsb);
        newsb.deleteCharAt(newsb.length()-1);
        System.out.println(newsb.toString());
    }

    private static void serialize(TrieNodeSD node, StringBuilder sb) {
        if (node == null) return;
        sb.append(node.character + ",");
        if (node.characters != null && node.characters.size() > 0) {
            for (Character c : node.characters.keySet()) {
                serialize(node.characters.get(c), sb);
            }
        }
        sb.append("#,");
    }

    // DOESN'T WORK!!
    private static TrieNodeSD deserialize(String[] data, int[] t) {
        if (t[0] >= (data.length-1) || data[t[0]].equals("#")) return null;
        TrieNodeSD node = new TrieNodeSD(data[t[0]].charAt(0));
        t[0] = t[0] + 1;
        TrieNodeSD child = deserialize(data, t);
        if (child != null) node.characters.put(child.character, child);
        return node;
    }

    private static TrieNodeSD buildTrienodeTree() {
        TrieNodeSD root = new TrieNodeSD('A');

        root.characters.put('B', new TrieNodeSD('B'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.put('E', new TrieNodeSD('E'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.put('F', new TrieNodeSD('F'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.get('F').characters.put('K', new TrieNodeSD('K'));

        root.characters.put('C', new TrieNodeSD('C'));

        root.characters.put('D', new TrieNodeSD('D'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('G', new TrieNodeSD('G'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('H', new TrieNodeSD('H'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('I', new TrieNodeSD('I'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('J', new TrieNodeSD('J'));

        return root;
    }
}

class TrieNodeSD {
    Map<Character, TrieNodeSD> characters;
    char character;
    public TrieNodeSD(char c) {
        this.characters = new HashMap<Character, TrieNodeSD>();
        this.character = c;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return this.character + "";  }
}
```

Serializing gives output in pre-order format (e.g. `A,B,E,#,F,K,#,#,#,C,#,D,G,#,H,#,I,#,J,#,#,#`).

`PROBLEM:` during de-serialization, the code doesn't process all the children correctly and doesn't associate them with correct parent.

Can someone suggest how to fix processing in `deserialize` method or help me with pointers what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the way to de-serialize a pre-order serialized form of Trie-Like data structure.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *                              A<br>
 *                  /           |           \<br>
 *                  B           C           D<br>
 *              /       \           /   /       \   \<br>
 *              E       F           G   H       I   J<br>
 *                      |<br>
 *                      K<br>
 * 
 *
 */
public class SerializeDeserialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder newsb = new StringBuilder();

        // prepare TrieNode Tree
        TrieNodeSD root = buildTrienodeTree();

        // serialize tree into string
        serialize(root, sb);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println();

        // construct tree again from serialized string
        TrieNodeSD newRoot = deserialize(sb.toString().split(","), new int[] { 0 });

        // Verify : again serialize above de-serialized tree to match both
        // trees serialized format.
        serialize(newRoot, newsb);
        newsb.deleteCharAt(newsb.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(newsb.toString());
    }

    private static void serialize(TrieNodeSD node, StringBuilder sb) {
        if (node == null) return;
        sb.append(node.character + ",");
        if (node.characters != null && node.characters.size() > 0) {
            for (Character c : node.characters.keySet()) {
                serialize(node.characters.get(c), sb);
            }
        }
        sb.append("#,");
    }

    private static TrieNodeSD deserialize(String[] data, int[] t) {
        if (t[0] >= (data.length - 1) || data[t[0]].equals("#")) return null;
        TrieNodeSD node = new TrieNodeSD(data[t[0]].charAt(0));
        while (true) {
            t[0] = t[0] + 1;
            TrieNodeSD child = deserialize(data, t);
            if (child != null) node.characters.put(child.character, child);
            else break;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private static TrieNodeSD buildTrienodeTree() {
        TrieNodeSD root = new TrieNodeSD('A');

        root.characters.put('B', new TrieNodeSD('B'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.put('E', new TrieNodeSD('E'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.put('F', new TrieNodeSD('F'));
        root.characters.get('B').characters.get('F').characters.put('K', new TrieNodeSD('K'));

        root.characters.put('C', new TrieNodeSD('C'));

        root.characters.put('D', new TrieNodeSD('D'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('G', new TrieNodeSD('G'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('H', new TrieNodeSD('H'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('I', new TrieNodeSD('I'));
        root.characters.get('D').characters.put('J', new TrieNodeSD('J'));

        return root;
    }
}

class TrieNodeSD {
    Map<Character, TrieNodeSD> characters;
    char character;

    public TrieNodeSD(char c) {
        this.characters = new HashMap<Character, TrieNodeSD>();
        this.character = c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.character + "";
    }
}
```

***Sample Run:*** Serialize given Trie-Like data structure in pre-order traversal, use the serialized string to construct Trie-data like data structure i.e. de-serialize and finally serialize it again to verify that the serialized form matches actual tree.

```
A,B,E,#,F,K,#,#,#,C,#,D,G,#,H,#,I,#,J,#,#,#

A,B,E,#,F,K,#,#,#,C,#,D,G,#,H,#,I,#,J,#,#,#
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your `trie data structure`, but if you are referring to the `trie` then there must be some misunderstandings.

There is a clear specification for [trie in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

> ...Unlike a binary search tree, **no node** in the tree stores the **key** associated with that node; instead, its **position** in the tree defines the key with which it is associated. All the descendants of a node have a **common prefix** of the string associated with that node, and the root is associated with the **empty** string...

<sub>(content from wiki, I just added the emphasis)</sub>

> PROBLEM: during de-serialization, the code doesn't process all the children correctly and doesn't associate them with correct parent.

Even for a tree structure with key in the node, still your solution won't work since you are ignoring the **size** of the children by using a `map` instead of a `fixed-sized` array which is quite essential to **deserialise** the serialised data.

Using `map` makes it impossible to determine which node is the parent and which nodes are the children.

As for `binary search tree` or the real `trie tree`, their structure are predefined, via which you then can **serialise** and **deserialise** the tree since they're deterministic.

---

Perhaps [Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) is what you really want.

By the way, you can actually *serialise* and *deserialise* directly in the `*Node`.

For example serialisation can something just like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TrieNode child : children) {
        if (child == null) resultList.add("#");
        else resultList.add(child.toString());
    }
    return resultList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Trie data structure definition, I have updated my question & requirement. Yes, it would be an option to add serialization & de-serialization in Node class itself but I have taken design choice where serialization & de-serialization logic stays out from object class or POJO. That gives flexibility to update serialization & de-serialization logic without disturbing clients who are using POJO & not serialization or de-serialization. I have no issues in serialization but I have issues in de-serializing the pre-order traversal serialized string.

Comment: @JRG It's not then a problem. But as I mentioned in the answer, your problems lies in the `map` you are using to store the data, which makes the tree deserialisation impossible since there is no clue to determine the parent and children node.

Comment: @JRG If you insist on using `map`, you can try to add the delimiter `{` and `}` to distinguish the parent and children nodes.

Comment: Yes, if you see my question, I was using `#` to indicate as end of the branch. `#` and position helped me to reconstruct the whole Trie-Like data structure. You can run my solution in IDE.